# Passing context from one view to the other

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I am attempting to pass a URL parameter to another `view` within my app. I currently have a function (`EntryListView`) that identifies what month you select, and then only shows the contents for that month. However, I would like the month to also be shown in the `detail` URL. This will enable a "go-back" button to navigate back to the month's page, as opposed to erroring out or navigating back to the landing page.

**urls.py As Is:**

```
url(r'entry/list/(?P<month>\w+)$', views.EntryListView.as_view(), name='entry-list'),

url(r'entry/detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'argent/detail.html'

class EntryListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'argent/index_list.html'
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        month = self.kwargs.get('month')
        ctx = super(EntryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # January
        if month == 'January':
            ctx['January17_qs'] = Entry.objects.filter(date__range=('2017-1-1', '2017-1-31'))

        # February17
        elif month == 'February':
        ctx['February17_qs'] = Entry.objects.filter(date__range=('2017-2-1', '2017-2-28'))

        # March
        elif month == 'March':
        ctx['March17_qs'] = Entry.objects.filter(date__range=('2017-3-1', '2017-3-31'))

        return ctx
```

**template**

```
<a href="{% url 'argent:entry-list' %}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back
                    </button>
            </a>
```

I currently get this error when using `{% url 'argent:entry-list' %}`:

`Reverse for 'entry-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tracker/entry/list/(?P<month>\\w+)$']`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the details's month to the `url` template tag as kwarg. Something like this should work.

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'argent/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['current_month'] = self.get_object().date.strftime("%B")
        return ctx
```

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'argent:entry-list' current_month %}">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go Back</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I seem to be getting this error when implementing this solution: `super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`. It is also telling me that "DetailView' is not an instance or a subclass of 'EntryListView'".

Comment: Oh ok, I had tried that but had not updated "current month". One more thing, I'm now getting an error that says: `'EntryListView' object is not iterable`. I now realize that I had not shown more than one month in my post, sorry about that. I have updated my post to include 3 months within `EntryListView`. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: Your question does not have any thing which can trigger `'EntryListView' object is not iterable.` error, check your code. If you just want to get the month of a entry detail so that you can show the link to list page, you can just do `{% url 'argent:entry-list' entry.date|date:"F" %}` to get the month of the current entry object.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. When I `print(ctx['current_month'])` within `DetailView`, however, I get "None". But, when I `print(month)` within `EntryListView` I get the month I am looking for, "November" for example. It does not seem to be pulling the data it needs. Could this be why it's giving me the error?

Comment: Sorry, I thought your current url conf is the "To be" url conf you posted. You can get the object's month and then pass it to template. see the updated answer.

Comment: No that's my fault for not specifying. Your final solution is exactly what I needed. Thanks again for all of your help!